# Using accumulate to calculate alternate sum

Tags: c++, accumulate

If I use the accumulate function in C++ like the below

```
 std::vector<int> v2{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
 int sum = 0;
 std::cout << std::accumulate(v2.begin(), v2.end())
```

It will simply sum all the numbers. But I wanted to calculate 1-2+3-4+5 
I was thinking of some way to accumulate 1,3,5 and 2,4 separately and then do it
But not sure how to achieve this using accumulate.

Comment: This is done by implementing custom iterators, that have this behavior, and then using the custom iterators with `std::accumulate`. Implementing custom iterators is a topic that's covered in advanced C++ textbooks. Do you know how to implement custom iterators?

Comment: As another alternative, *negate* every second element in the vector, and use `std::accumulate` as normal.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik Or a lambda suffices depending on the requirement. Is the negation strictly positional, or does the value determine it? OP doesn't provide enough information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my quick solution :

```
int sign = -1; // start with minus first (e.g. 1-2)
std::vector<int> values{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

auto value = std::accumulate(values.begin(), values.end(), 0, [&sign](int total, int value)
{ 
    sign = -sign;  
    return total + (sign)*value;
});
```

Comment: Does `std::accumulate` make a guarantee of order when applying the operation? It's a genuine question. Most standard algorithms don't, so this has potential to break if `std::accumulate` does something novel.

Comment: Mmm... never mind. The presence of `std::reduce` implies it does operate in order.

Comment: @Pepijn Is it possible to move the function passed to accumulate outside? Also, I am a little confused about what does [&sign] means

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica That is a good question :) 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate states that accumulate uses a left fold. Checking with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function).
And my conclusion is, yes it proceeds in left to right order through the values in the vector :)

Comment: @sunny Yes it can be a seperate function. But if you only use the function in one place a lambda is a good option. A lambda is basically a function (object) without a name.
[&sign] means capture the sign variable by reference so it can be modified from within the lmabde function.  More info here : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica oh... on your never mind: good deduction too :)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't bother with `std::accumulate` at all here, it's not really suitable.  Instead, just use two loops:

```
int result = 0;
size_t n = v2.size ();
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i += 2)
    result  += v2 [i];
for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i += 2)
    result -= v2 [i];
```

Comment: In my opinion, using std::algorithm options mean you re-use tested code.
They use iterators on containers so in the end you can usually also refactor code.
Though this is more important in large projects then home use code.

Comment: Lambda's aren't trickery, they're a full feature of C++ :)
And I've been using them so long now writing them is second nature (pretty much like a for loop).
And this is not a unique discussion we're having : https://www.sandordargo.com/blog/2020/05/13/loops-vs-algorithms
In the end I like code with less "for" statements in it, lets call it personal style :)

Comment: It's a two-line lambda, there nothing obscure in it.

Comment: @PepijnKramer That's true in general, but standard algorithms should not be abused. Keep it simple and don't violate semantics of algorithms. To me, two loops look much clearer than `std::accumulate` with an alternating `sign` variable. That code works, but it raises unneeded questions about its correctness (is the order of lambda calls guaranteed?) and functionality (which sign will the first term have?).

Comment: @PepijnKramer It also breaks the [semantics](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) of `std::accumulate` - *Computes the sum of the given value and the elements in the given range*. You're not supposed to change this meaning by using tricky lambdas. This makes code harder to understand and maintain. All these are red flags, and in our code base I would definitely prefer raw loops to that version of `std::accumulate`.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to calculate 1-2+3-4+5
>
> I was thinking of some way to accumulate 1,3,5 and 2,4 separately and then do it

This is a very good approach to the problem. The standard library doesn't have a `stride` view yet (though it does have `drop`), and with that you could write

```
int sum = accumulate(v2 | stride(2), 0) -
          accumulate(v2 | drop(1) | stride(2), 0);
```

You can do this with the range-V3 library until `stride` is added.